# Ruby regex method

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I need to get the expected output in ruby by using any method like `scan` or `match`.

Input string:

1. `"http://test.com?t&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1"`
2. `"http://test.com?t&r12=1&r124=1"`

Expected:

1. `r12=1,r122=1, r1=1, r124=1`
2. `r12=1,r124=1`

How can I get the expected output using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `/r\d+=\d+/`:

```
"http://test.com?t&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1".scan(/r\d+=\d+/)
# => ["r12=1", "r122=1", "r1=1", "r124=1"]

"http://test.com?t&r12=1&r124=1".scan(/r\d+=\d+/)
# => ["r12=1", "r124=1"]
```

You can use `join` to get a string output. Here:

```
"http://test.com?t&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1".scan(/r\d+=\d+/).join(',')
# => "r12=1,r122=1,r1=1,r124=1"
```

**Update**

If the URL contains other parameters that may include `r` in end, the regex can be made stricter:

```
a = []
"http://test.com?r1=2&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1&ar1=2&tr2=3&xy4=5".scan(/(&|\?)(r+\d+=\d+)/) {|x,y|  a << y}
a.join(',')
# => "r12=1,r122=1,r1=1,r124=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

While input strings are urls with queries, I would safeguard myself from the false positives:

```
input = "http://test.com?t&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1"
query_params = input.split('?').last.split('&')
#⇒ ["t", "r12=1", "r122=1", "r1=1", "r124=1"]
r_params = query_params.select { |e| e =~ /\Ar\d+=\d+/ }
#⇒ ["r12=1", "r122=1", "r1=1", "r124=1"]
r_params.join(',')
#⇒ "r12=1,r122=1,r1=1,r124=1"
```

It’s safer than just `scan` the original input for any regexp.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it with regex correctly, you'll need to use a regex like this:

```
puts "http://test.com?t&r12=1&r122=1&r1=1&r124=1".scan(/(?:http.*?\?t|(?<!^)\G)\&*(\br\d*=\d*)(?=.*$)/i).join(',')
puts "http://test.com?t&r12=1&r124=1".scan(/(?:http.*?\?t|(?<!^)\G)\&*(\br\d*=\d*)(?=.*$)/i).join(',')
```

[Sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaURfd1hLRFpISDg) output:

```
r12=1,r122=1,r1=1,r124=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
r12=1,r124=1
```